# passing switch case value to html element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body >


   <button onclick="me('${message}');">hello</button>
<div id="play">

</div>
<div id="p">

</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function me(mes)
   {

       switch(mes){
       case 'Knowing our Numbers':

           var newElement = "<object id='objViewer' width='250' height='250' type='video/x-ms-asf' data='Wildlife.wmv' classid='CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6'><param name='url' value='Wildlife.wmv'><param name='filename' VALUE='Wildlife.wmv'><PARAM name='autostart' VALUE='0'><param name='uiMode' value='full'><param name='autosize' value='1'><param name='playcount' value='1'><EMBED TYPE='application/x-mplayer2' src='Wildlife.wmv' NAME='MediaPlayer' id='wmvViewer' autostart='false' WIDTH='250' HEIGHT='250' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0'></EMBED></object><br/>";

        $("#p").html(newElement);
          alert(mes);     

       break;
       case 'Whole Numbers':
           alert(mes);
        break;      

           }

}


</script>



</html>
```

In the above code i am trying to pass the switch case variable to html element but it is not working.i need to play the video based on the case selection in the script whats wrong in my code give me the idea to slove

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is jquery reference?

Comment: You have already asked this question several times tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was a beautiful answer! It didn't even occur to me to check if he had jQuery installed. I just kind of went into auto pilot.